# bootstrap: Adding more than one svg tag in my navbar deletes my container content

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4, icons

I'm using the [Jumbotron Example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/jumbotron/) from the Bootstrap Examples and got a weird issue when using more than one icon in my navbar. When I add in anything behind the first icon, 2/3 of my class "container" just disappears. When inspecting the Element it's like they have been deleted.

**EDIT: Apparently the issue is connected with the Live Server Extension for Visual Studio Code, simply opening the index.html shows everything correct.**

Navbar Code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
      aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chat" fill="currentColor"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M2.678 11.894a1 1 0 0 1 .287.801 10.97 10.97 0 0 1-.398 2c1.395-.323 2.247-.697 2.634-.893a1 1 0 0 1 .71-.074A8.06 8.06 0 0 0 8 14c3.996 0 7-2.807 7-6 0-3.192-3.004-6-7-6S1 4.808 1 8c0 1.468.617 2.83 1.678 3.894zm-.493 3.905a21.682 21.682 0 0 1-.713.129c-.2.032-.352-.176-.273-.362a9.68 9.68 0 0 0 .244-.637l.003-.01c.248-.72.45-1.548.524-2.319C.743 11.37 0 9.76 0 8c0-3.866 3.582-7 8-7s8 3.134 8 7-3.582 7-8 7a9.06 9.06 0 0 1-2.347-.306c-.52.263-1.639.742-3.468 1.105z" />
        </svg>
      </ul>
      <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chat" fill="currentColor"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M2.678 11.894a1 1 0 0 1 .287.801 10.97 10.97 0 0 1-.398 2c1.395-.323 2.247-.697 2.634-.893a1 1 0 0 1 .71-.074A8.06 8.06 0 0 0 8 14c3.996 0 7-2.807 7-6 0-3.192-3.004-6-7-6S1 4.808 1 8c0 1.468.617 2.83 1.678 3.894zm-.493 3.905a21.682 21.682 0 0 1-.713.129c-.2.032-.352-.176-.273-.362a9.68 9.68 0 0 0 .244-.637l.003-.01c.248-.72.45-1.548.524-2.319C.743 11.37 0 9.76 0 8c0-3.866 3.582-7 8-7s8 3.134 8 7-3.582 7-8 7a9.06 9.06 0 0 1-2.347-.306c-.52.263-1.639.742-3.468 1.105z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Main and Container Code:

```
<main role="main">

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a
          jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta
            felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
            massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

  </main>
```

I changed barely anything from the example, I only deleted the navbar content.

Screenshot with one Icon (as intented):
[image: Screenshot with one Icon (as intented)]

Screenshot with two Icons (with missing content):[image: two icons; missing content]

Comment: `collapse navbar-collapse` from this please remove `collapse` to show two icons

Comment: `.collapse {display: none;}`
collapse class doesn't show the icon

Comment: your HTML is not valid: you have a list `<ul>` wilt no `<li>` but with an `<svg>` element inside

Answer (score 0):

Please remove class `collapse` from `collapse navbar-collapse`

```
.collapse{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<main role="main">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
      aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chat" fill="currentColor"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M2.678 11.894a1 1 0 0 1 .287.801 10.97 10.97 0 0 1-.398 2c1.395-.323 2.247-.697 2.634-.893a1 1 0 0 1 .71-.074A8.06 8.06 0 0 0 8 14c3.996 0 7-2.807 7-6 0-3.192-3.004-6-7-6S1 4.808 1 8c0 1.468.617 2.83 1.678 3.894zm-.493 3.905a21.682 21.682 0 0 1-.713.129c-.2.032-.352-.176-.273-.362a9.68 9.68 0 0 0 .244-.637l.003-.01c.248-.72.45-1.548.524-2.319C.743 11.37 0 9.76 0 8c0-3.866 3.582-7 8-7s8 3.134 8 7-3.582 7-8 7a9.06 9.06 0 0 1-2.347-.306c-.52.263-1.639.742-3.468 1.105z" />
        </svg>
      </ul>
      <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-chat" fill="currentColor"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M2.678 11.894a1 1 0 0 1 .287.801 10.97 10.97 0 0 1-.398 2c1.395-.323 2.247-.697 2.634-.893a1 1 0 0 1 .71-.074A8.06 8.06 0 0 0 8 14c3.996 0 7-2.807 7-6 0-3.192-3.004-6-7-6S1 4.808 1 8c0 1.468.617 2.83 1.678 3.894zm-.493 3.905a21.682 21.682 0 0 1-.713.129c-.2.032-.352-.176-.273-.362a9.68 9.68 0 0 0 .244-.637l.003-.01c.248-.72.45-1.548.524-2.319C.743 11.37 0 9.76 0 8c0-3.866 3.582-7 8-7s8 3.134 8 7-3.582 7-8 7a9.06 9.06 0 0 1-2.347-.306c-.52.263-1.639.742-3.468 1.105z" />
      </svg>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a
          jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta
            felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
            massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

  </main>
```

Comment: Check this @rekalar

Comment: removing "collapse" does nothing on my project..even copying the whole code snippet doesn't change the error, but when I run your code snippet in stackoverflow it works.. maybe an issue with firefox? I will try another browser.

EDIT: I opened up the project in google chrome, still doesn't work.